# Нужно ли добавлять в git *iml?

Tags: git, android-studio

Создаю проект и заливаю его на `github`, после чего когда копирую проект с `git` на новом месте то `Android Studio` жалуется что не найдены модули и указывает на отсутствие `*iml` файлов и проекта не видно в `AS`. Такая штука появляется всегда когда ипользую какие-то дополнительные `dependency`. После нажатия "Refresh all Gradle projects" создаются новые файлы `*iml` и все работат.

Собствнно почему так? Надо ли `*iml` грузить на `git`(тоесть убрать их из `gitignore`) или надо в `AS` где-то в настройках установть чтобы оно само автоматом создавало `*iml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если шарите его как Gradle проект, что собственно рекомендуется, то не надо.

Если же как IDEA проект, лень потом импортировать, то надо.
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

**ADDON**: Gradle проект после скачивания не надо сразу открывать в Android Studio, а надо импортировать в него, тогда создадутся все вспомогательные файлы, типа *.iml и проект корректно откроется.

Comment: `Если же как IDEA проект, лень потом импортировать` - искоренять надо такую лень! )) Gradle, Maven, SBT и прочие системы сборки на то и придуманы, чтобы хранить конфигурацию и окружение как код и не версионировать кучу файлов, особенно бинарных.

Comment: Я проект на самом деле не копирую, а даю ссылку на него в `AS`  `check out from project from VC` =>`clone repositore`. Это разве не то же самое что и импрот? И все же если я буду заливать `*iml` это ни кому не навредит?

Comment: Нет, это не импорт. Это вы просто используете AS как клиента системы контроля версий. То же самое можно сделать и из коммандной строки или с использованием других клиентов типа Tortoise.

Comment: Так вот, после `check out from project from VC` студия предложит открыть проект, надо сказать нет. Потом пойти `File -> New -> Import Project` или как-то так и импортировать скачанное как Gradle project.